# "Shipping address is not set" error when saving cart

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart

I have a simple code, where i add a simple product to the cart

> $cart = $obj->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
>   $cart->addProduct(5, 3); 
>   $cart->save();

but the last row, returns this error:
Fatal error: `Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException: Shipping address is not set`

Why is necessary to add a shipping address to save the cart?

How i can add an address programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

`\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart' class has been deprecated from`100.1.0`.

Use `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote`instead
Please check 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e5479b4e7b87b8ad22dc1ca8e4c33556999da5f2

Answer (score 0):

**You can add shipping address programmatically by following code..!**

=> **event.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="sales_quote_save_after">
            <observer name="sales_quote_save_after_event" instance="Test\Module\Observer\SalesQuoteSaveAfter" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

=> **Test/Module/Observer/SalesQuoteSaveAfter.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace Test\Module\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class SalesQuoteSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
    {
        protected $addressFactory;

        public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address) 
        {
            $this->address = $address;
        }

        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

            if (!$quote->hasItems()) 
            {
                $quote->setBillingAddress($this->getEmptyAddress())->setShippingAddress($this->getEmptyAddress());
            }
        }

        private function getEmptyAddress() 
        {
            $this->address->setRegionId(0);
            $this->address->setRegion("");
            $this->address->setRegionCode("");
            $this->address->setCountryId("");
            $this->address->setStreet([""]);
            $this->address->setCompany("");
            $this->address->setTelephone("");
            $this->address->setFax("");
            $this->address->setPostcode("");
            $this->address->setCity("");
            $this->address->setFirstname("");
            $this->address->setLastname("");
            $this->address->setMiddlename("");
            $this->address->setEmail("");
            $this->address->setSameAsBilling(1);
            $this->address->setSaveInAddressBook(0);
            return $this->address;
        }
    }
```